# Adding meta description with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, meta-tags

I am trying to add meta descriptions to HTML via the following jQuery code:

```
var stringmeta = '<meta name="description" content= ' + shortd + '>' 
$("head").append(stringmeta);
```

`shortd` is a string that I am passing directly. However, I see the output as in HTML like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="TV" at="" your="" fingertips="" anytime="" everywhere.="">
```

The expected output is

```
<meta name="description" content="TV at your finger tips anytime everywhere.">
```

Answer (score 1):

Attribute values containing spaces must be delimited with quote characters.

```
var stringmeta = '<meta name="description" content="' + shortd + '">'
```

And, of course, you'll need to make sure that `shortd` doesn't contain any `"` characters which would prematurely end the attribute value.

```
var stringmeta = '<meta name="description" content="' + shortd.replace(/"/g, "&quot;") + '">'
```

But mashing up strings to do that is silly. We have DOM methods which will take care of figuring out quote marks and escaping for us, and if you're using jQuery anyway, it will wrap those functions in its own API.

```
const $meta = $("<meta />")
    .attr("name", "description")
    .attr("content", shortd);
```

But having said all that, most tools which pay any attention to meta description are unlikely to look for it after executing any JavaScript in the page, so this is probably a pointless exercise.